# Configure ASP .NET 5 for Oracle/Entity Framwork

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

What do I need to do to add Entity Framework for Oracle with ASP .NET 5?  I'm going against an Oracle database version 10.2.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need Oracle Data Provider for .NET (ODP.NET). Please find it in the link below.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

Comment: I went and installed the VS 2015 version of the tool and it looks like it will give me ADO .NET style connection to the database.  This will work for me because all I need to do is read the records and write them out to a text file.  It doesn't look like Oracle supports EF 7 yet.  Just EF 6 and I'm not sure if that's compatible with ASP .NET 5.